# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de radio button en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un problema con una grilla, al ingresar los datos por formulario me muestra todos los datos menos los que selecciona en un radio `button`, al ver por consola que valor está tomando el resultado es `undefined`.

Este es mi código:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data, grid, dialog;
    data = [];

     dialog = $('#dialog').dialog({
        title: 'Agregar/Editar',
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height:250,
        width:600,
        modal: true
    });
    function Edit(e) {
        $('#Item').val(e.data.id);
        $('#Cantidad').val(e.data.record.Cantidad);
        $('#unidadMedida').val(e.data.record.unidadMedida);
        $('#descripcion').val(e.data.record.descripcion);
        $('#condicion').val(e.data.record.condicion);
        $('#activoFijo').val(e.data.record.activoFijo);
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        $('#button').show();
    }
    function Delete(e) {
        if (confirm('¿esta seguro que desea eliminar este registro?')) {
            grid.removeRow(e.data.id);
            if(grid.count()!=0){
                $('#button').show();
            }else{
                $('#button').hide();
            }
        }
    }
    function Save() {

        if ($('#Item').val()) {
            var id = parseInt($('#Item').val());
            grid.updateRow(id, { 'Item': id, 'Cantidad': $('#Cantidad').val(), 'unidadMedida': $('#unidadMedida').val(), 'descripcion' : $('#descripcion').val(), 'condicion' : $('#condicion').val(), 'activoFijo' : $('#activoFijo').val() });
        } else {
            grid.addRow({ 'Item': grid.count() + 1, 'Cantidad': $('#Cantidad').val(), 'unidadMedida': $('#unidadMedida').val(), 'descripcion' : $('#descripcion').val(), 'condicion' : $('#condicion').val(), 'activoFijo' : $('#activoFijo').val() });
        console.log($('#Cantidad').val());
        console.log($('#activoFijo').val());
        }
        dialog.close();
        $('#button').show();
    }

    grid = $('#grid').grid({
        dataSource: data,
        columns: [
            { field: 'Item', width: 32 },
            { field: 'Cantidad' },
            { field: 'unidadMedida', title: 'Unidad de Medida' },
            { field: 'descripcion', title: 'Descripcion' },
            { field: 'condicion', title: 'Condicion'},
            { field: 'activoFijo', title: 'Activo Fijo (si-no)'},
            { width: 50, tmpl: '<a href="#"><img src="img/editar.png"></a>', align: 'center', events: { 'click': Edit } },
            { width: 50, tmpl: '<a href="#"><img src="img/eliminar.png"></a>', align: 'center', events: { 'click': Delete } }
        ]

    });
    $('#btnAdd').on('click', function () {
        $('#Item').val('');
        $('#Cantidad').val('');
        $('#unidadMedida').val('');
        $('#descripcion').val('');
        $('#condicion').val('');
        $('#activoFijo').val('');
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    });

    $('#btnSave').on('click', function(){
        if(comprobarCamposRequired()){
            Save();
        }else{
            alert("llene todos los campos");
        }

    } );
    // $('#btnSave').on('click', comprobarCamposRequired);
    $('#btnCancel').on('click', function(){

        dialog.dialog("close");
    });

     $('.solo-numero').keyup(function (){
            this.value = (this.value + '').replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
          });

     $(function($){
                $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
                    closeText:'Cerrar',
                    currentText:'Hoy',
                    monthNames:['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
                    monthNamesShort:['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
                    dayNames:['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
                    dayNamesShort:['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Juv','Vie','Sáb'],
                    dayNamesMin:['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sá'],
                    weekHeader:'Sm',
                    dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy',
                    firstDay:1,
                    isRTL:false,
                    showMonthAfterYear:false,
                    yearSuffix:''
                };
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);  

    });

             $("#fchFecha").datepicker({
                  changeMonth: true,
                  changeYear: true,
                  showOn: "button",
                  buttonImage: "img/calendar.gif",
                  buttonImageOnly: true,
                  showAnim: "drop",
                  buttonText: "Selecione una Fecha"
    });
             $('#button').hide();

     function comprobarCamposRequired(){
            var correcto=true;
            var campos=$('input[type="text"]:required');
            var select=$('select:required');

            $(campos).each(function() {
                if($(this).val()==''){
                    correcto=false;
                    $(this).addClass('error');
                }       
        });

    $(select).each(function() {
            if($(this).val()==''){
                correcto=false;
                $(this).addClass('error');
            }
        });
    return correcto;

    }

    $('input[type="text"]:required').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('error');
    });

   

    var hoy = new Date();
            dia = hoy.getDate();
            mes = ((hoy.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' : '') + (hoy.getMonth() + 1);
           anio = hoy.getFullYear();
    fecha_actual = String(dia+"/"+mes+"/"+anio);
    $("#fchFecha").val(fecha_actual);
            
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="js/grid.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <link   href="css/grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
        <script src="js/dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <link   href="css/dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
        <script src="js/draggable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/valida.js"></script>
        <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css" media="screen" /> 

    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Departamento originador:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="nomDepOri"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>APE N°</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="apeN"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Centro de beneficio:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="centBene"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Fecha de emisión</td>
                        <td width="80"><input type="date" id="fchFecha" readonly="readonly"  /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <hr>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Sívase coordinar el retiro del siguiente material dado de baja</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><button id="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Agregar</button></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <table id="grid"></table>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <table id="button">
                     <tr>
                         <td><button>Guardar</button></td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
                  <div id="dialog" style="display:none">
                        <input type="hidden" id="ID">
                        <form>
                        <table border="0" class="tablePopup">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="80">Cantidad</td>
                                <td width="160">Unidad de Medida</td>
                                <td>Condición</td>
                                <td>Activo Fijo</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>                                
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" id ="Cantidad" name="Cantidad"  class="solo-numero" maxlength="2" required>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select id ="unidadMedida" required><option  value="" >Seleccione...</option>
                                              <option  value="litros">Litros</option>
                                              <option  value="kilos">Kilos</option>
                                              <option  value="bulto">Bulto</option>
                                              <option  value="lote">Lote</option>
                                              <option  value="equipo">Equipo</option>
                                              <option  value="piezas">Piezas</option>
                                              <option  value="unidad">Unidad</option>
                                </td>
                           
                                <td>
                                    <select id ="condicion" required><option  value="">Seleccione...</option>
                                              <option  value="Bueno">Bueno</option>
                                              <option  value="Malo">Malo</option>
                                              <option  value="Regular">Regular</option>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="radio"  name="activoFijo" value="Si" >Si
                                    <input type="radio"  name="activoFijo" value="No" >No
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Descripción</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td scope="colgroup" colspan="4"><textarea cols="65" maxlength="1500" id="descripcion">ewdd</textarea></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                          <table border="0" class="tablaButton">
                              <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-default">Save</button></td>
                                <td width="80"><button type="button" id="btnCancel" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </form>
                    </div>
              
             </td>
         </tr>
     
     </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Estás seleccionando los radios por ID pero no les has puesto ID. Puedes seleccionar directamente el radio seleccionado por medio de la propiedad `checked`.

```
let activoFijo = $('input[name="activoFijo"]:checked').val();
```

Comment: lo he puesto directo en el js, este me muestra como resultado en el formulario [object Object].
'activoFijo' : $('input[name="activoFijo"]:checked')

Comment: ya lo arregle, le agregue el .val() al final
$('input[name="activoFijo"]:checked').val()

gracias :)

Comment: ¿Tú eras la de la pregunta? Ni cuenta me dí jaja

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener el valor del radio button puedes utilizar la propiedad `:checked`:

```
$('input[name=nombreRadio]:checked', '#nombreFormulario').val()
```

Esto te devolverá el valor del radio button que esté seleccionado.

Answer (score 2):

Esta sería la forma de hacerlo con *JavaScript*:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="activoFijo"]:checked').value
```